# Combinations : How to calculate all possible combinations of points awarded for match results guesses game

Tags: python, python-3.x

Myself and a group of people "bet" on which teams will win on different football matches results (no money involved). There are 3 possibilities of points being awarded to the player.

`points = [0, 3, 4]`

So, if I say team A will win 1-0.

- If team A loses, I get no points.
- If team A wins, I get 3 points.
- If team A wins 1-0, I get an additional point, for a total of 4 points.

So, for that specific bet I can get 0, 3, or 4 points. So does everybody else who participated in the bet. So I was trying to get all possible combinations of results. For two players, I want to be able to obtain this kind of output (example for two players):

```
"Player 1"    0   0   0   3   3   3   4   4   4
"Player 2"    0   3   4   0   3   4   0   3   4
```

I used to have an Excel file that used VBA to calculate these possible results, but the number of players was fixed, so the code did not adapt to adding or removing players.

I'm trying to create a function that can calculate and output some data structure with all possible combinations of results, for different (and a dynamic) number of players.

I have read several questions (10+) about combinations in python but none of those cover this specific scenario. They usually cover using `itertools` for permutations (not the case because we can all have the same result), for multiple combinations (won't work if the number of combinations exceed the values of the possible results (3). I did manage to get something similar to what i need by using:

```
string_points = str(points[0])+str(points[1])+str(points[2])

for p in itertools.product(string_points, repeat=3):
    print(p)
```

The result is a sequence of tuples with string values of the possible results:

```
('0', '0')
('0', '3')
('0', '4')
('3', '0')
('3', '3')
('3', '4')
('4', '0')
('4', '3')
('4', '4')
```

But being strings, I can't perform any operations on them or calculate statistics...

**Is there any way to make this work using itertools? 
Would anyone suggest a different approach altogether? I am open to any kind of solution. 
Is there any kind of data structure that can incorporate the name of the players to the possible results? Thanks in advance...**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to turn the values into strings in the first place!

```
for p in itertools.product(points, repeat=2):
```

This will get you ordered pairs of ints.

Specifically what you want is the *Cartesian product* of your points-list with itself, *n* times (where *n* is the number of players). That's exactly what `itertools.product` with the `repeat` keyword gets you.

Comment: Wow, I was misled by a different post in which specified that that product would only work with the components of a string. My bad for not testing it further. Thanks for that Draconis! Any input on how to create an efficient data structure with all that info?

Comment: @Fabri Depends what you want to do with it: for printing, a list of pairs should be fine.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I want to add those possibilities to previos scores, maybe add the product of a following match. I’ll experiment with different things and not take any more of your time. Thanks for the help man! Can’t believe it got pass me after reading all these posts...